# Fail attempt on passing data from form to controller

Tags: php, laravel, forms, controller, laravel-livewire

This is my form

```
<form action="{{ route('file.keep',['id'=>$fieldequip->id]) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   @csrf
   <input
      type="file"
      name="file"
      id="inputFile"
      class="form-control pt-2 pl-2 -mx-2 text-xs  font-bold  rounded @error('file') is-invalid @enderror">
   <div class = "pt-1">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-700 text-xs py-1 px-4 font-bold w-1/3 rounded">Upload</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-purple-500 hover:bg-purple-700 text-xs py-1 px-4 font-bold rounded">Download</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Which goes through this route

```
 Route::post("/uploadszz/{id}",[\App\Http\Livewire\Breakdowns::class, 'keep'])->name('file.keep');
```

That i need the data `$id` in this livewire component controller

```
/**
* Display a listing of the resource.
*
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function keep(Request $request,$id)
{
$request->validate([
'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv|max:2048',
]);
$file = $request->file('avatar');
$file->storeAs('avatars', $id, 's3');
/*
Write Code Here for
Store $fileName name in DATABASE from HERE
*/
return back()
->with('success','You have successfully upload file.')
->with('file', $fileName);
}
```

Somehow it keeps appearing `Too few arguments to function App\Http\Livewire\Breakdowns::keep()` error, what did I do wrong in the data passing process?

Comment: inspect and check form action whether `$fieldequip->id` has value or not.

Comment: The url after clicking the button is ```http://localhost:8000/uploadszz?id=1```. It has value, i think the problem is when retrieving the value from the url

Comment: why id is query parameter rather than a url parameter?? your route is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function keep(Request $request,$id)
{
$request->validate([
'file' => 'required|mimes:pdf,xlx,csv|max:2048',
]);
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $file->storeAs('avatars', $id, 's3');

    return back()
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload file.')
        ->with('file', $fileName);
} else {
    return back()
        ->with('error','Error')
        ->with('file', $fileName);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem still persists, I think its not because of error handling but more about failing to retrieve the value from controller.

Comment: $request->file('file')